# 405 Error When Calling API From WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I need to get some data from an API using an access token and a body so I made the following (randomised the keys and ids):

```
add_action('rest_api_init', 'wp_rest_user_endpoints');

function wp_rest_user_endpoints($request) {
  register_rest_route('wp/v2', 'users/register', array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'wc_rest_user_endpoint_handler',
  ));
}
function wc_rest_user_endpoint_handler($request = null) {
  $response = array();
  $parameters = $request->get_json_params();
  $userid = sanitize_text_field($parameters['data[attendeeid]']);
  $body = array(
      'accountid' => '121209102910',
      'key' => 'asjkajskauweiajksakajsakjsaks',
      
  );

$args = array(
    'body'   => $body,
);

$response = wp_remote_post( 'https://api-na.eventscloud.com/api/v2/global/authorize.json', $args );
$body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
$data = json_decode( $body );
$accesstoken = $data->accesstoken;

if($accesstoken ) {
    
   $body = array(
      'accesstoken' => $accesstoken,
       'eventid' => '29102901920129',
       'attendeeid' => '1212121902910920',
      
  );
   
   $args = array(
    'body'        => $body,
);
   
   $response = wp_remote_post( 'https://api-na.eventscloud.com/api/v2/ereg/getAttendee.json', $args );
//Do something with this
 }
}
```

However, the issue I have is that when I get the accesstoken and then go to make my request to go and get the user I get a 405 error message back from the API. I have tried making the same request manually through Postman and the request worked so is there somewhere I'm going wrong with my WordPress code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realised I was using wp_remote_post rather than wp_remote_request (so doing a POST rather than just a GET). Once I did that, it worked fine.